# How can I configure cmake to stop leaving .ninja_log files lying around?

Tags: cmake, ninja

As a developer, I want to reduce file clutter on my machines. For example, I often run `make clean` when I temporarily put away a software project. This reduces noise in the project directory tree, and frees up disk space.

However, when run `cmake --build . --target clean`, then cmake leaves behind a TON of junk files.

I can work around most of these junk files, by appending a rather extensive boilerplate list of the names in an `ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES` directory property:

```
set_property(
    DIRECTORY .
    APPEND PROPERTY
    ADDITIONAL_CLEAN_FILES
    "html;${EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH};debug;debug.log;Makefile;build.ninja;.ninja_deps;Testing;CTestTestfile.cmake;CMakeFiles;CMakeCache.txt;cmake_install.cmake;conanbuildinfo.cmake;conanbuildinfo.txt;conaninfo.txt;graph_info.json;conan.lock"
)
```

However, appending `;.ninja_log` in this string has no effect. cmake appears to forcibly regenerate this file after every task, including `cmake --build . --target clean`. So there is that one annoying junk file leftover in all my cmake + ninja projects: `.ninja_log`.

I also tried working around this by declaring a custom cmake cleanup task:

```
add_custom_target(clean-ninja-log COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E rm -f .ninja_log)
```

With the same results.

Currently, my operational workaround is to *wrap* cmake in yet another build system:

https://github.com/mcandre/rez

And have the outer build system run some C++ standard library calls to remove this file.

Another similar workaround involves writing a custom `clean.ninja`, `clean.mk`, `clean.sh`, or similar script. But these tend to limit portability, assuming either `rm` or `del` based commands. And it's annoying to have to use TWO scripting systems for basic things. I want a cmake task that works like `make clean`, for full project cleaning.

But if at all possible, I would prefer a solution that works in 100% cmake. Maybe I can configure cmake to stop running `ninja -t restat` after every single cmake task?

Comment: You seem confused what CMake is and what is a `clean` target. CMake generates files, which can be used by a **build tool** for build the project. E.g., if you specify "Unix Makefiles" as [cmake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), then after running `cmake` you could build the project using `make`. Construction `cmake --build . --target clean` is just a synonym for `make clean`. Or it is a synonym for `ninja -t clean` in case of Ninja generator. `make clean` doesn't remove `Makefile`, `ninja -t clean` doesn't remove `.ninja_log`.

Comment: If you want to remove all files generated by CMake for a build tool, then simply drop the entire build directory: `rm -r <build dir>`. (Assuming you have performed out-of-source build).

Comment: rm is not portable. It fails on Command Prompt.

Comment: Well, if you want a portable way to delete a directory, then you could use [command line tool of cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-rm): `cmake -E rm -r <build_dir>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of source builds significantly improve cmake littering.

- `conan install --install-folder <build directory>` allows conan to integrate with cmake out of source builds.
- `cmske -B <custom build directory>` organizes the artifacts into a convenient directory, that is easier to remove.
- `cmake -E rm -rf <build directory>` removes the cmske artifacts in a portable way.
- `cmake -P` allows custom clean targets to be scripted in a way that doesn't have to trigger .ninja-log repopulation
- `cmake_path()` and `EXPAND_TILDA`enable portable path construction during cmake shell command targets.

But I mostly just use `rez`.